# How to extract all function and variable names from Matlab code

Tags: regex, matlab, compiler-construction

Given Matlab source code, how would one go about extracting all function and variable names used in it?

Context: I would like to find all dependencies of an anonymous function handle excluding its arguments.
For example:

```
y=2;
anon = @(x) f1(x,y);
```

f1 and y are the identifiers I'm interested in.

Comment: Reegular expressions maybe.

Comment: This is a super interesting question, though I think you could provide substantially more detail as to exactly what you are trying to get.  Depfun or matlab.codetools.requiredFilesAndProducts will return this for an m-file, but I'm not aware of anything that does it for an anonymous function.  If you can run the function, perhaps you could get it from the output info from profiling the function: profile on; anon(some_value); S = profile('info').   S should contain the full call stack from running the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with matlab, but I came up with this regex pattern to find all variables in matlab code:

```
(?!(?:for|if|end)\b)\b[A-Za-z_]\w*\b(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*$)
```

[Demo.](http://regex101.com/r/aI8qB9/1)

This is, however, a far easier task for regex than finding all variables *except* function parameters is. If you don't have access to a powerful implementation of regex, this will require some effort. I don't know what programming language you want to use, but here's the gist of it:

1. Find all anonymous functions using this regex pattern:
   `@\(\s*\w+(?:\s*,\s*\w+)*\s*\).*?;`
2. For each anonymous function:

   1. Find all parameters to the function. You can use this pattern `@\(.*?\)` to extract the function head, then use the abovementioned pattern to extract all variables.
   2. Find all variables used in the function body. This `\).*` pattern will extract the anonymous function's body. Next, again, extract all variables from the function body.
   3. Remove all parameters (found in step 1) from the variables (found in step 2), and you're left with the "external" variables.

---

Explanation of the regex patterns:

finding variables:

```
(?! // assert this isn't a keyword like "for" or "if"
    (?:for|if|end)
    \b
)
\b // in order for the previous assertion to work, we must now match a word boundary.
// Otherwise, the "or" in "for", the "nd" in "end", etc. would still match.
[A-Za-z_] // now, match a word character
\w* // and any more subsequent word characters and digits
\b // up to the next word boundary (this isn't really necessary, but I believe it makes the pattern faster)
(?! // finally, assert this word is not enclosed in quotes ''
// we'll count how many single quotes ' there are in this line
    (?: // consume as many pairs of single quotes as possible
        [^']*'
        [^']*'
    )*
    [^']*' // consume one last single quote
    [^']*$ // and make sure there are no more single quotes in this line
)
```

finding anonymous functions:

```
@\( // match "@("
\s* // whitespace
\w+ // consume the first parameter
(?: // consume subsequent parameters, if any:
    \s* // whitespace
    , // a comma
    \s* // some more whitespace
    \w+ // and the next parameter
)*
\s* // whitespace again
\) // closing brace, end of parameter list
.*? // now simply consume the function body: everything...
; //...up to the next semicolon.
```

Comment: Is it possible to identify member function calls? e.g. obj.func()

Comment: @Leo: If you want to match `obj.func` as one instead of `obj` and `func` separately, try this pattern: `(?!(?:for|if|end)\b)[A-Za-z_]\w*(?:\.[A-Za-z_]\w*)*\b(?!(?:[^']*'[^']*')*[^']*'[^']*$)`

Answer (score 1):

Just found that there is a matlab command called `functions` that looks like it does what you want

```
>> f1 = @(x) prod(x, y);
>> y = 2;
>> functions(f1)
ans = 
 function: '@(x)prod(x,y)'
     type: 'anonymous'
     file: ''
workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
>> ans.workspace{1}
   ans = 
   y: 2
```

And if you want all the dependencies below that, you can run the function under profile mode

```
profile on; 
f1(3);
S = profile('info'). S.FunctionTable.FunctionName will have all of the functions that get called during execution of the anonymous function.
```

Comment: workspace contains every variable visible at the point of definition of f1, not only dependencies of f1.

Comment: When I run `functions`, `workspace` does not contain every variable visible, only the variables that have already been defined and that are dependencies of `f1`.  But if `f1` has dependencies on variables not yet defined, then they are not contained in `workspace`.  Either way, I do not get "every variable visible at the point of definition", only the relevant ones.

Comment: try to define an irrelavant variable z=100 before f1's definition, and you'll see it's in the workspace

Comment: Tried this, and I don't get irrelevent variables in my `workspace`, maybe this is a difference in matlab versions?  Trying your example right now: `z = 100;
y = 2;
f1 = @(x) mean(x, y);
A = functions(f1);
>> A.workspace{1}
ans = 
    y: 2`.  Not sure why we see this difference; I'm using 2014A. Anyway, seems like this syntax won't work for you. Perhaps the profiler commands in the answer above will do what you want; if not, I'm looking forward to seeing a better answer for this, because I think the question is super interesting.

Comment: Is the workspace field documented somewhere?
If this indeed works all that is left is to get the dependent functions, but I cannot use the profile approach you suggest because running f1 may be expensive, or it may change the state and I am not allowed to affect the result of the code. Perhaps a combination with the answer of @Rawing could help.